# Chrome, how to disable new copy paste URL converter

Tags: google-chrome, url, uri

Example, in the newest version of Chrome on Windows type in: `http://example.com/api/<test>` or copy paste it from here into the URL. Then hit enter. After that **copy** it with CTRL + C from the URL Bar, it is important that it is copied from the URL Bar.

Now my issue is that, when you hit CTRL + V this is what comes out:

`http://example.com/api/%3Ctest%3E`

but I don't want it to be like that it should be like this

`http://example.com/api/<test>`

is there a flag for it or something to disable this?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I disable the new copy paste URL converter in Chrome?

URL encoding by Chrome for copied URLs is not a new feature, relatively speaking. In regards to disabling it, there is no flag for this as far as I am aware (though Firefox had one at one point).

The only solution I've ever come across to this issue is to use an extension, such as [Copy Unicode URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp).

For the suggested extension, once it is installed, an icon should appear on your address bar. Left-click the icon to copy the current URL without URL encoding.

[image: Copy Unicode URLs - Screenshot]

It is probably also worth noting that the extension adds a `Copy unicode URL` option to the right-click context menu for links embedded in a web page.